# $\{u_{k}\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that converges to $u$. Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \langle u_{k}, v \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{u_{k}\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that converges to
>   $u$. Prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \langle u_{k}, v \rangle = \langle
> u, v \rangle$

Here, $\langle u, v \rangle$ denotes the inner product of $u$ and $v$.

---

My attempt:

Okay, so I want to show $\forall \epsilon  > 0$,  there exists some index $K$ such that

$$\left|\langle u_{k}, v\rangle - \langle u, v\rangle\right| < \epsilon $$

for all $k \geq K$. Using the definition of an inner product, we can write

$$\left|\langle u_{k}, v\rangle - \langle u, v\rangle\right| = \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_{k_{i}} v_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}v_{i} \right| = \left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}(u_{k_{i}} - u_{i}) \right| = |\langle u_{k} - u, v\rangle|$$

I don't know how to finish from here. I think we need to use the fact that $\lim_{k\to\infty u_{k}} = u$. Since we know $\{u_{k}\}$ converges to $u$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $K'$ so that for $k \geq K'$, the quantity $|u_{k} - u_{i}|$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Triangle inequality. Note each component goes to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the linearity of the scalar product and the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality

Comment: I am having trouble finishing

Comment: Where do we use linearity? I can apply C-S Inequality to get $|\langle u_{k} - u, v\rangle| \leq ||u_{k} - u|| \cdot ||v|| = \text{dist}(u_{k}, u) \cdot ||v||$. So, do I define my index to be $K = K' \cdot ||v||$, where $K'$ is the index for which $\text{dist}(u_{k}, u) < \epsilon$ for all $k \geq K'$?